# Name/value pair loop of JSON Object with Java & JSNI

Tags: java, json, gwt, loops, jsni

With GWT, how would I go about looping through a JSON object or array, which has been returned via a JSNI method, that I could also extract both name and value pairs per loop?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using JavaScriptOverlay types or JSONObject like types?

So in case of JSONObject like types and assuming **data** is of type JSONObject 
you can do following:

```
json_string = "{'data':{'key':'test','key2':'test3','key3':'test3'}}"
JSONObject json_data  = JSONParser.parseLenient(json_string);
JSONObject data = json_data.get("data").isObject();
Set<String> keys = data.keySet();
for (String key : keys) 
{
   String value = data.get(key).isString().stringValue();
}
```